# Love2D game and editor in two separate programs

Tags: architecture, lua, love2d

I'm building an engine in Love2D and I need to build an editor who will create scenes with game objects I wrote in lua.

The thing is that there's this guy in my team who said : "Don't include the editor within the game, make it separate from it so you won't load the whole editor with the game itself"

So I'm asking how could I achieve this type of structure, because I want my libraries to be shared between the game and the editor.

```
- MAIN FOLDER 
    | - core
    |   | core features of the engine
    | - editor
    |   | main.lua
    | main.lua
```

I can't see how I'll be able to require files with this structure, is there a specific way to do this kind of thing in lua ?

What I'm trying to do now is this :

*main.lua (game)*

```
require "core/engine"

function love.load()  -- This works
    print("Loaded")
end
```

*main.lua (editor)*

```
require "../core/engine"

function love.load() -- Won't work
    print("Loaded")
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, found it !

I had to add this to the *main.lua* file in the editor folder and it worked :

```
package.path = package.path .. ";../?.lua"
require "core.engine"
```